# How to prevent Bootstrap 4 dropdown to show on input element click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, event-propagation

Following is a simple bootstrap dropdown menu, with the exception that the toggle element is a text input.
I don't want the dropdown menu to show on `click` event, rather, I want to show it on user input, so that I can dynamically populate the menu based on that input.

The `click` event handler below prevents the dropdown from showing before the user has input anything in the input element, and when there is any input, the `input` handler shows the dropdown menu. However once the user has input something into the element, and dropdown has shown. Afterwards, the any subsequent `click` on the input element shows the dropdown menu, and the `click` handler runs but does not prevent the dropdown from showing even if the user clears all input.

Does Bootstrap attach any new events, or am I not understanding events very well? How could I make this work?

```js
$('#exampleFormControlInput1').on('click', e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Dropdown prevented');
});

$('#exampleFormControlInput1').on('input', e=>{
  $('#exampleFormControlInput1').dropdown('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label" id="dropdownMenuButton1">Input with autocomplete</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Search for something" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleFormControlInput1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add new click handlers. Use Bootstrap's events and methods instead:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/#methods

To prevent the dropdown from opening when the input field is empty, block the `show.bs.dropdown` event. Note that:

> All dropdown events are fired at the `.dropdown-menu`’s parent element and have a `relatedTarget` property, whose value is the toggling anchor element.

To show the list when data appears in the field, and hide when the field becomes empty, you can use the `.dropdown()` method.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/RwZMNzE?editors=1011

```js
$(function() {

  // prevent the list from opening by clicking on an empty field
  $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
    if (!e.relatedTarget.value) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  // handle changes in the input field
  $("#exampleFormControlInput1").on("input", function(e) {
    if (this.value) {
      $(this).dropdown("show");
    } else {
      $(this).dropdown("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label" id="dropdownMenuButton1">Input with autocomplete</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Search for something" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleFormControlInput1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```